# How to Explode a Textarea Field and Echo each line separately, wrapped with HTML

Tags: php, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

Need to take an advanced custom field textarea and display it in my template by breaking out each line separately. I want to wrap each line of the textarea with HTML, like an `<li>`.

I've tried the following, but it's just not working:

```
if (isset($instruction_textarea)){
    $arry=explode( "\r\n", $instruction_textarea );
}
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($arry); $i++){
    echo (trim($arry[$i])+"<br/>");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $instruction_textarea); // or use PHP PHP_EOL constant
if ( !empty($lines) ) {
  echo '<ul>';
  foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
    echo '<li>'. trim( $line ) .'</li>';
  }
  echo '</ul>';
}
```

It should work.

Comment: PHP_EOL relates to the server's end of line character, not the client which submitted the data. They can be different.